# jQuery hide/show div using variables

Tags: jquery

I am a nOOb to jQuery.

I want to use variables in jQuery to hide/show divs.

what I have so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#listMenu a').click(function () {
            var getPage = $(this).attr("id");
            var getName = $(this).attr("name");
            //console.log(getPage);
            //console.log(getName);

            $("#" & getName ).show();



    });
});
```

firebug console shows that I have the vars correctly,
but I get this error next:

this[H].style is undefined
[Break on this error] (function(){var R=/((?:((?:([^()]+)...typeof K==="string"?K:K+"px")}})})();

any help is appreciated.
sjs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you wanted to write

```
$("#" + getName ).show();
```

& is not an operator in javascript, but + is.

Comment: not to be a stickler, but you should accept the answer if it was the solution for you.

Answer (score 3):

use `$("#" + getName ).show();`

`+` will concatenate strings.