# Hide/Show Div on button click using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

This is supposed to be my first Jquery code that I am writing. I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464768/jquery-hide-show-div-using-variables) and many more examples to make the simplest jquery code to display Hello on Button Click(W3Schools worth mentioning). I am trying to show a div that contains the Hello in it on a button click.

```
<div>
<input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" value="click me">
</div>

<div id="Create" style="visibility:hidden">
Hello
</div>

@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(btn).click(function () {
        $(Create).show();

    });
});
</script>
}
```

I have tried writing the Script code many places like in the head, after the Scripts.Render, before it. I am not really sure where i should place the Jquery code.

I have this code appended to a MVC5 application. This code is written for learning purpose. I think the other code in the View is irrelevant for the working of the Jquery.

Comment: **1.** Use *display: none* on element `<div id="Create" style="display: none">`  **2.** Use *toggle* instead of show. `$(btn).click(function () {$(Create).toggle();});`

Comment: @Tushar Of course it should be `$('#Create').toggle();`

Comment: Use `$("#Create").toggle();`.

Comment: Its `$('#Create').show();` (quotes and hash)

Comment: The problem is that `show` function is to replacing `display:none` to `display:block` but not `visibility:hidden' to `visibility:visible`

Comment: what errors do you get in the console, is btn,Create defined someplace?

Comment: Yes thanks for all your comments and the downvote.. No issues, i got it  to work.. @SpencerWieczorek : The issue was with the $ and qoutes

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  i did what you have commented. thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<div>
<input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" value="click me">
</div>

<div id="Create" style="display:none">
Hello
</div>

@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $("#Create").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You Ca Check it here
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("p").hide();
          });
          $("#show").click(function(){
            $("p").show();
          });
         });
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>

       <p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

       <button id="hide">Hide</button>
       <button id="show">Show</button>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btn").click(function () {
     $("#btn").click(function () { $("#Create").show();
   });
});
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Code has a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Sure, If this is your first jQuery code.

You can take help of W3Schools.

Your answer is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Practice</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Create").hide();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#btn", function() {
        $("#Create").show();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" value="Click Me">
</div>

<div id="Create">Hello
</div>
```