# Hide/Show div on specific page with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

Right then I am newish to website code, and I'm self teaching. I'm currently building a new website which can be seen here: www.magik-arts.com with the password Testing 123.

The issue I have at present is I have certain div elements that I want to be able to hide and show on specified pages. for example I have a side nav which is visible on the main page /the-journey which I do not want to be visible on any of the other pages.

I have however used ajax loading on my site, and due to this the css display: none is not working or triggering.

I'm now at a roadblock as I have no idea of how to get it to work so any help or guidance would be much appreciated. I think I will have to do the hide and show using jquery but I don't yet know how to specify using a set page.

Do I need to do a .click action to trigger a display: none toggle? or is there a proper way to do it?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide/Show Div on button click using Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251749/hide-show-div-on-button-click-using-jquery)

Comment: Also, please read this: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a lot of possible answers to your questions, I'll try to give you as much answers as I can, with details.

### 1) Include the Sidebar only on pages you want it to be displayed ( using PHP )

If you want your sidebar to be on, let's say, only 3 pages out of 5, then create a `sidebar.php` file with your sidebar code in it, and `include` this page on the pages you want your sidebar on.

Read more at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

### 2) With jQuery

You can set your sidebar `hidden` and .toggle it whenever you want it to be displayed. It can be easily done using jQuery, here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/g5bwwtvd/

Obviously, you can change the `.toggle` method and let jQuery detect the current page the user is on, and depending on which page he is on, `.toggle` ( or not ) the sidebar.

Keep in mind that this is not a proper way to do it, just mentionning it so you know.

### 3) Using CSS ( not recommended )

You can include a specific css stylesheet whenever you do not want to display your sidebar, and in this stylesheet you hide your sidebar with `visibility: hidden`, and `display: none`. Keep in mind that doing that is not a good way to do so, since you write more code to hide something.

I recommand the `ìnclude` method, since that is a good way to do it, and it works with nearly every language, not only web ones.

## EDIT : Adding example for JavaScript.

### HTML

```
<div class="sidebar" hidden> // Hidden sidebar
  <p>
    I am the sidebar
  </p>
</div>

<p class="path">
</p>
```

### JavaScript / JQuery

```
$(function(){

    var currPath = window.location.pathname; // Gets the current pathname ( /_display/ )

  $('.path').text('Current path is : '+ currPath);
  if(currPath == '/webpage.html'){ // Checks if the pathname equals the webpage you want the sidebar to be displayed on
    $('.sidebar').toggle(); // Set the sidebar to visibility: visible and display: block
  }else {}

})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/doo5xzf4/4/)

If you want to properly understand the code, change the  `if(currPath == '/webpage.html')` to  `if(1 == 1)`, the sidebar will now be displayed properly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that - If I wanted to do it with jquery how would I specify the page in which it was supposed to show? and all else is hidden?

I have been doing as much searching and trying as possible but it doesn't seem to work along side the ajax...

Comment: Pretty simple actually, you just have to set the sidebar's default css to `visibility: hidden` and `display: none`, then using JavaScript you parse the url in order to get the current location, and if the result equals the page you want to display the sidebar on, then you set the sidebar's css to `visible` and the display to `block`. Read this for more : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: Ok I'm starting to get it I think, or maybe not (your help is much appreciated)

So what I need to do is start the code with: 
`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
"The full URL of this page is:<br>" + window.location.href;`

and then after that I need to add a class toggle right? or am I not along the right lines?

Comment: Please check my answer, I edited it with a working example and some comments. Do not forget to "accept" my answer in order to help other people with the same question.

Comment: Ok I've done that - as some follow up , I have put the code in and got the path name and that part of the code is working as it is displaying the path name on the page.

My only issue now is that it's not hiding or showing, did I need to add anything else specific? I have not got a `display: none;` added in css nor have I got the hidden written in the html like you have?

Do I need to add anything specific? Sorry your help has been very useful, and I'm so close to getting it working

Comment: Please edit your question with the new code in order to help me understand this new issue. I'll try to help you then.

Comment: Don't worry, I was having a mind block moment, it's all working now, so thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: how would I be able to get this to work with multiple pages? I have changed the code to do this: `if(currPath == '/services','/about-us','/magik-arts'){` but it isn't working? for some reason it won't remove the class or show something as per the jquery that follows, you can see the code here in full: https://jsfiddle.net/MAGiKARtS/84xLgdqj/ thanks